# Expectation of a random variable (R.V.)

Tags: statistics, random-variables, statistical-inference, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I'm a beginner in statistics and in particular in R.V. I need a slow and detailed explanation of the facts below.
For an event $A$, I understand that the indicator random variable $1_A$ is $1$ if $A$ occurs, and $0$ otherwise. 
**Why then** $P(A)=E[1_A]$
and **why**
$$E_\theta[1_A]=E_\theta[E_\theta[1_A∣X]]\ ?$$
**Anyway, what is $E_\theta$ here ?**

**EDIT :**

We consider two definitions of the **power function** which equivalence is unclear to me.

(1) The power function of a test, denoted by $Q(\theta)$ is the probability of rejecting null hypothesis $H_0$ when $\theta\in \Theta$ is the true parameter
value. The power function is then given by
$$Q(\theta)=P_\theta(\cal R).$$

We have obviously here $Q(\theta_0)=\alpha$ and $Q(\theta_1)=1-\beta$
where $\alpha$ is the I type error and $\beta$ is the II type error.

(2) A function $\psi(.):\cal X^n\to [0,1]$ is called the critical function
where $\psi(\mathbb{x})$ stands for the probability with which the null hypothesis $H_0$ is rejected when the data $\mathbb{X}=\mathbb{x}$ has been
observed, $\mathbb{x}\in \cal X^n$.

**Why** now, we can rewrite the power function defined in (1) as follows

$$Q(\theta)=E_\theta\{\psi(\mathbb{X)}\}$$ for $\theta\in \Theta$ ?
Where comes the expected value under the true $\theta$ from?

**EDIT2:**

$$P_\theta(\text{reject}) = E_\theta[1_{\text{reject}}] = E_\theta[E_\theta[1_{\text{reject}} \mid X]] = E_\theta[\psi(X)].$$

$$P_\theta(\text{reject}) = E_\theta[1_{\text{reject}}] = E_X[E_\theta[1_{\text{reject}} \mid X]] = E_X[\psi(X)].$$

$$P_\theta(\text{reject}) = E_\theta[1_{\text{reject}}] = E_\theta[E_X[1_{\text{reject}} \mid X]] = E_\theta[\psi(X)].$$

Comment: You should tell us what $E_\theta$ is, I certainly don't know.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case. The second equality is the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). The $E_{\theta}$ is used mainly to emphasize that the expectation depends on $\theta$ in the context of inference where $\theta$ is some unknown quantity, but it is the usual expectation.

Comment: $E_\theta[E_\theta[1_A∣X]]$ looks strange.  Should it be $E_X[E_\theta[1_A∣X]]$ ?

Comment: @Henry I do not know. But still why $$E_\theta[1_{\text reject}]=E_X[E_\theta[1_{\text reject}|X]]$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definitions you are using, but really the best formulation is that we have some measure $\mathbb{P}$ on the underlying space of events where $E[1_A]:= \int 1_A d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(A)$. So it pops straight out of definitions if you define everything a certain way. If this doesn't make sense/or fit with your definitions, you'll have to give more context.

Comment: A beginner would not know measure.

Comment: I mean depends on if you are a beginner in probability but mathematically mature (OP has a good bit of rep so not impossible). Elementary probability theory is a bit of a mess without being able to use measure.